# Install Hbase on windows: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool

Tags: hadoop, hbase

After installing HBase v0.94.x, I am getting the error on running start-HBase.sh

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
running master, logging to C:\hbase/logs/hbase--master-hp.out
: running regionserver, logging to C:\hbase/logs/hbase--regionserver-hp.out
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old HBase version?

Comment: Because I'm working on an old project. I have even tried the latest stable version i.e. 2.2.4 but still getting the same error.

Comment: 1) The problem is with the `hbase classpath` command. 2) I'm not sure HBase is tested on Windows